# convert for loop to while (remove break <-- this is key)

Tags: python, loops

The `break` here is bothering me; after extensive research I want to ask if there is a pythonic way to convert this to a `while` loop:

```
import re

file = open('parse.txt', 'r')
html = file.readlines()

    def cleanup():
    result = []
    for line in html:
        if "<li" and "</li>" in line:
            stripped = re.sub(r'[\n\t]*<[^<]+?>', '', line).rstrip()
            quoted = f'"{stripped}"'
            result.append(quoted)
        elif "INSTRUCTIONS" in line:
            break
    return ",\n".join(result)
```

I really am trying to practice designing more efficient loops.

added parse.txt

```
<p style="text-align:justify"><strong><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">INGREDIENTS</span></strong></p>

    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">3 lb ground beef (80/20)</span></li>
<ul>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">1 large onion, chopped</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">2-3 cloves garlic, minced</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">2 jalapeño peppers, roasted, peeled, de-seeded, chopped</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">4-5 roma tomatoes, roasted peeled, chopped</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">1 15 oz can kidney beans, strained and washed</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">2 tsp salt</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">2 tsp black pepper</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">2 tsp cumin</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">¼ - ½ tsp cayenne pepper</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">1 tsp garlic powder</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">1 tsp Mexican oregano</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">1 tsp paprika</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">1 tsp smoked paprika</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">3 cups chicken broth</span></li>
    <li style="text-align:justify"><span style="background-color:#ecf0f1">2 tbsp tomato paste</span></li>
</ul>

<p style="text-align:justify"><strong>INSTRUCTIONS</strong></p>

<ol>
    <li style="text-align:justify">Heat a large put or Dutch oven over medium-high heat and brown the beef, while stirring to break it up. Cook until no longer pink. Drain out the liquid.</li>
    <li style="text-align:justify">Stir in onions and cook for about 5 minutes until they are pale and soft. Add in minced garlic and jalapeño peppers, stirring for another minute.</li>
    <li style="text-align:justify">Stir in the chopped tomatoes, all the spices, and tomato paste until well-distributed and tomato paste has broken up, then follow with the broth. Allow the pot to come to a gentle boil over medium heat, uncovered for about 20 minutes.</li>
    <li style="text-align:justify">Reduce heat to low, cover and simmer for at least 3 hours, until liquid has reduced.</li>
    <li style="text-align:justify">During the last 20-30 minutes of cook time, add in the kidney beans; uncover and allow liquid to reduce further during this time.</li>
    <
    li style="text-align:justify">Serve hot with jalapeño cornbread muffins, shredded cheese, avocado chunks, chopped cilantro, chopped green onion, tortilla chips.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: `break` is absolutely fine here. You don't need parentheses around `html` (just a stylistic issue) and have `file` not closed (`with open(...) as file: html = file.readlines()` should be preferred - this issue is much worse). `break` in a `for` loop is efficient and (IMO) most readable here. You should create `stripped` and `quoted` only on demand, though: you use them only in first `if` branch and just waste for non-`li` lines.

Comment: theoretically, you can replace `break` with something like `done=False; while not done.... if something: done = True`, but that would make little sense.

Comment: @SUTerliakov nice suggestion on the stripped and quoted part..I fixed the parentheses too around html.. I don't get what you mean on the file .readlines() though..

Comment: @gog is a ``while`` even possible?.. I want the challenge.

Comment: You should provide an example of parse.txt

Comment: `if "<li" and "</li>" in line` is not doing what you think.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value

Answer (score 1):

We could move the `break` into another function,
if you feel it improves the clarity of the top-level function.
The core notion is that we've no need to lavish
attention on a few million irrelevant lines that
might follow an occurrence of the "INSTRUCTIONS" terminator.

A few observations on the topic of "laziness":

- Notice that we compile the regex just once.
- We invoke the regex only on the subset of lines where it's needed.
- We do **not** read the whole file, as there might be a great many lines after "INSTRUCTIONS".

```
def up_through_instructions(filespec):
    with open(filespec) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
            if "INSTRUCTIONS" in line:
                break

def cleanup():
    pattern = re.compile("[\n\t]*<[^<]+?>")
    result = []
    for line in up_through_instructions("parse.txt"):
        if "<li" in line and "</li>" in line:
            stripped = pattern.sub("", line).rstrip()
            result.append(f'"{stripped}"')
    return ",\n".join(result)
```

---

Ok, fine, let's say for some crazy reason `break`
is not allowed to be part of the design space.

We've a Turing machine at our disposal.
It's not that hard to code it in an alternate way.
But what matters is: "Would future engineers
find the alternate approach easier to maintain?"

(Spoiler: my vote is "no!")

```
def alternate_up_through_instructions(filespec):
    with open(filespec) as f:
        done = False
        while not done:
            try:
                line = next(f)
                yield line
                done = "INSTRUCTIONS" in line
            except (StopIteration, EOFError):
                done = True
```

I really do **not** recommend adopting this approach.
The `try` is expensive, and we're doing it many many
times. Not only is a `for` iteration the more
natural pythonic way to approach this, but it
is far more efficient.

Notice that there are two terminators we must respect:
"INSTRUCTIONS" and EOF. One we test for, the other
is detected via an exception.

Comment: yes; I fixed regex into the ``if``

Answer (score 0):

You can use the underlying iterator Python provides to turn your for-loop into a while-loop without a break:

```
def cleanup():
    result = []
    i = iter(html)
    line = ""
    while i.__length_hint__() and not "INSTRUCTIONS" in line:
        line = next(i)
        if "<li" in line and "</li>" in line:
          stripped = re.sub(r'[\n\t]*<[^<]+?>', '', line).rstrip()
          quoted = f'"{stripped}"'
          result += [quoted]
    return ",\n".join(result)
```

The call to `__length_hint__()` might slow your loop down as it tries to determine the length of a list. Using `except StopIteration` as suggested by `iter()` solutions can be way faster but complicates the code more:

```
def cleanup():
    result = []
    i = iter(html)
    line = ""
    try:
      while not "INSTRUCTIONS" in line:
        line = next(i)
        stripped = re.sub(r'[\n\t]*<[^<]+?>', '', line).rstrip()
        quoted = f'"{stripped}"'
        if "<li" in line and "</li>" in line:
            result.append(quoted)
    except StopIteration:
      pass
    return ",\n".join(result)
```

More solutions using iteration in combination with len() as suggested by J_H:

```
def cleanup():
    result = []
    i = iter(html)
    line = ""
    l = len(html)
    while l and not "INSTRUCTIONS" in line:
        l -= 1
        line = next(i)
        if "<li" in line and "</li>" in line:
          stripped = re.sub(r'[\n\t]*<[^<]+?>', '', line).rstrip()
          quoted = f'"{stripped}"'
          result += [quoted]
    return ",\n".join(result)

def cleanup():
    result = []
    line = ""
    l = 0
    while l < len(html) and not "INSTRUCTIONS" in html[l]:
        if "<li" in html[l] and "</li>" in html[l]:
          stripped = re.sub(r'[\n\t]*<[^<]+?>', '', html[l]).rstrip()
          quoted = f'"{stripped}"'
          result += [quoted]
        l += 1
    return ",\n".join(result)
```

The solution with break might still be the fastest and simplest solution beside of the `try/except` version.

At last a use of list comprehension:

```
def cleanup():
    return ",\n".join ( [ '"'+re.sub(r'[\n\t]*<[^<]+?>', '', line).rstrip()+'"'
      for line in html [
        :([i+1 for i,l in enumerate(html) if "INSTRUCTIONS" in l]+[len(html)])[0]
      ] if "<li" in line and "</li>" in line
    ] )
```

Where

```
([i + 1 for i, l in enumerate(html) if "INSTRUCTIONS" in l] + [len(html)]) [0]
```

obtains the first position of "INSTRUCTIONS" or just the whole length. I am not fully sure if the last version is 100% bugfree as list comprehension is kinda awkward and hard to read in this case.
The good thing about this is you get a list and don't really need a function call any more.

Comment: I never saw this method before.. https://www.pythoninsight.com/2018/08/length-hints-in-python/

Comment: zomg, no, do **not** use `while i.__length_hint__() ...` in that way, it is an abuse of the defined protocol. The "hint" part tells you not to take it too seriously -- it is intended as a malloc() optimization. Use `len()` in this context. Prefer the second example; it is much better than the first (except for the part where it whether "<li" needs to be in the string).

Comment: Snerd requested a while-loop without a break and the `try/except` code is pretty much similar to a break, that is why I used `__length_hint__`."<li" fixed, thanks for mentioning